# Intermittent connection drops for unknown reasons in Win7

Tags: windows-7, networking, router

After about 12 to 24 hours of up time, my desktop's connection will drop out for a minute and re-establish, and then usually repeat this once per hour, sometimes less frequently during the day. It is connected via ethernet to the modem router, and other devices on the LAN like my laptop and Playstation don't experience this dip. I'm not running via any VPN on the desktop.

I updated all my drivers for the chipset, the ethernet adapter, and got my BIOS on the latest revision. I ran through Google and OpenDNS doing the entire flush/renew/release/register commands via ipconfig. I ran `netsh winsock reset` and  `netsh int ip reset`. I blew out all my browser caching and other temp files. I disabled ipv6. I ran CCleaner to clean out old registry business. I checked my MTU and it was set to 1500 as was suggested. I reset my Windows Firewall config. I installed a fresh copy of Win 7. I assigned a static IP via the router. I changed my antivirus from AVAST to Kaspersky. I switched to USB3-to-Ethernet adapter instead of my onboard adapter. I used different ethernet cables and different router ports.

I am still experiencing the disconnect on the desktop and only the desktop.

Almost everything drops out for about a minute. Streaming to Twitch and online multiplayer stop, as does the discord bot I have running in nodejs and audio streams running through the browser. Those last two are the only things that give me any hint into what's going on because I can't find anything about network logging on Win7.

The errors that the nodejs connection and the internet radio in Chrome's console are both network resets: `ECONNRESET` and `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)` respectively. Chrome also has `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE` that is sometimes before or after the reset. After that I get a few `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` and then `ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED` from Chrome, and a `ENOTFOUND` from the nodejs before things resume as normal.

I'm nearly out of ideas. A coworker suggested that I might have a RAM issue, so I'm running Memtest at the moment. I'm going to try running the machine through my laptop with ICS to see if the connection still drops, and then reset the router to factory default. I might call the ISP and see if they know anything, but if its only on one machine in the connection that seems unlikely.

These other tests are going to take at least a day to check, so I wanted to if anybody knew anything because I'm at the limits of my IT knowledge and googling ability.

e1: will be looking at the Application and System event logs next time the issue occurs, as well as attempting to to ping my router, my laptop via hostname and the next hop gateway. I will also try to resolve DNS hostnames with nslookup, but when I attempted to hit new uncached web sites via Chrome during this issue I was hit with the could not resolve error. The window of failure is small so it may take a few times, but thank you for the first suggestions.

e2: The system logs in the event viewer shows "The Computer Browser service has entered the running state" followed by "The TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service was successfully sent a stop control. The reason specified was: 0x4030011 [Operating System: Network Connectivity (Planned)]". A quick google search suggested that I disable the disable the Power Management setting for the ethernet driver that lets the system disable it. Going to see what happens.

e3: After disabling the power management for the ethernet adapter, disabling the Computer Browser and TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper services, I'm still experiencing the disconnects. I re-enabled the services and used the NetBIOS being stopped event for some simple powershell scripts to ping the router and laptop, tracert and nslookup.

e4: Interestingly enough, all my logs happen on the 26 minute count once per hour from 11PM to 6AM this morning, I'm curious if it will happen again at 7:26. What I have is this:

nslookup was unable to resolve google.com during an outage.
ping would usually hit one or two instances of `transmit failed: General failure` before being able to reach the router. 
tracert was unable to reach the google and never got off the first stage.

Comment: Anything relevant logged to the System or Application event logs when the problem occurs? When it happens can you ping your router? Your ISP's next hop gateway? Can you successfully resolve DNS hostnames with nslookup? Please do not only respond in the comments. Instead, [edit] the post with this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point the router's DHCP settings were changed to expire after an hour. However, for some reason the initial lease was being put out for 24 hours. When other systems would connect like the laptop or PS4, they would be powered off/disconnected from the router before they expired. The desktop was still connected after 24 hours so every consecutive hour after that the DHCP lease would refresh and kill everything.

After resetting the DHCP lease the hourly disconnect cycle was broken. ipconfig says the next lease is for tomorrow and there's been no disconnects since then.

Thanks for suggesting looking at the Event Viewer, seeing that the disconnects were almost perfectly at hour intervals was the clue that lead me here.